# Sort string contains numbers, NSMutableArray with Dictionaries

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

strings like

```
"4 Miles 400 stones"
"2 Miles 10 stones"
"6 Miles 2 Stones"
```

a key value of dictionary in `NsMutableArray`, I am trying to sort them by the amount of miles then stones.

regular `sortUsingDescriptor` :

`[list sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"systems" ascending:YES], nil]];`

or `NSNumericSearch` :

```
NSMutableArray *newList;
        NSArray *result = [list sortedArrayUsingFunction:&sort context:@"systems"];
        newList= [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:result];

NSInteger sort(id a, id b, void* p) {
    return [[a valueForKey:(__bridge NSString*)p]
            compare:[b valueForKey:(__bridge NSString*)p]
            options:NSNumericSearch];
}
```

are not working.

Do I have to parse the string get numbers then sort it? or is there an easier way to sort this?

Comment: I might make a custom class that holds these values as a numeric type and simply override the `description` method to print in this format rather than trying to store and sort the data as strings.

Comment: what is the key, what the value??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is correct,

I have tried your way of

```
NSInteger sort(id a, id b, void* p) {
    return [[a valueForKey:(__bridge NSString*)p]
            compare:[b valueForKey:(__bridge NSString*)p]
            options:NSNumericSearch];
}
```

it is sorting correctly  make sure you call correct dictionary value or correct method, put some break points, you may be sending null values or something.

if you want to reverse the search just use

```
NSInteger reverseSort(id a, id b, void* p) {
    return - [[a valueForKey:(__bridge NSString*)p]
            compare:[b valueForKey:(__bridge NSString*)p]
            options:NSNumericSearch];
}
```

Comment: yeah, damn after putting breaking points I have seen that I was sending empty string

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it the **best, object-oriented** way.

First. Create a class. Let's call it `MyObject`:

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger miles;
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger stones;

+ (MyObject *)objectWithString:(NSString *)string;

@end
```

As you can see, it has a `objectWithString` that we will use to create objects using information in a string like: `"4 Miles 400 stones"`.

```
@implementation MyObject

+ (MyObject *)objectWithString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[0-9]+?(?= Miles | stones)" options:0 error:nil];
    NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

    MyObject *myObject = [[MyObject alloc] init];

    myObject.miles = [[string substringWithRange:((NSTextCheckingResult *)matches[0]).range] integerValue];
    myObject.stones = [[string substringWithRange:((NSTextCheckingResult *)matches[1]).range] integerValue];

    return myObject;
}

- (NSString *)description
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d miles, %d stones", self.miles, self.stones];
}

@end
```

Then, we will use **`NSSortDescriptor`** to sort our array:

```
MyObject *myObject1 = [MyObject objectWithString:@"4 Miles 400 stones"];
MyObject *myObject2 = [MyObject objectWithString:@"2 Miles 10 stones"];
MyObject *myObject3 = [MyObject objectWithString:@"6 Miles 2 stones"];

NSArray *array = @[myObject1, myObject2, myObject3];

NSSortDescriptor *miles = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"miles" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *stones = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"stones" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[miles, stones];

NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSLog(@"Sorted: %@", sortedArray);
```

And the output:

```
2014-03-05 19:51:54.233 demo[12267:70b] Sorted: (
    "2 miles, 10 stones",
    "4 miles, 400 stones",
    "6 miles, 2 stones" )
```

It works like a charm my friend!